# Computer reacting weird to RAM configurations

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a very old computer a dell vostro 200 slim and it's playing up again.

[PC MANUAL](http://www.crash-bg.com/CATALOG/computers/Dell_vostro_200.pdf)

The computer has worked fine for quite some time with 2 matched 1GB RAM modules  and 2 mismatched 1GB ones.

But now when I boot the computer up with all 4 RAM modules it refuses to start and just beeps (one beep every so often which according to the manual indicates a motherboard issue).

Here are the configurations I've tried red is matched RAM.

[image: image representation of configurations tried.]

This indicates no pattern in the failures and goes completely against what the manual proposes. I've been at it for the past 5 hours but nothing please help???

Also if i buy 2 more red ones will all 4 red ones work?

Comment: If the computer was working fine until a certain moment, could the memory modules have slightly gotten out of the sockets, or the sockets have just a bit of dust on them? Try to clean every space inside and around the sockets and insert the modules in the original configuration, making sure they are well fixed (with the help of the plastic clips).

Comment: Verify each stick works by itself and run Memtestx86.  My guess you have a bad stick.

Comment: Where did you find these colorful pictures?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov LOL, I made them on paint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions from your manual?

1. It is recommended not to put original stick with others, see at highlighted picture below.
2. It is recommended to disconnect PCI-E card, see at highlighted picture below.
3. It is recommended to discharge static electricity from your body, see at highlighted picture below.
4. It is said put it in DIMM1 when alone, so you can check all sticks one by one, see at highlighted picture below.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Include here please your updated results. It will allow anyone to get more understanding and give a better answer.

Comment: terribly sorry I've been locked out of the internet for some time I will definitely post back with updates

Comment: Thanks for you help, **THE REASON** for the behaviour was actual physical damage there is a hairline crack on the ram module

Comment: Happy to know that you have found it out.